# How can I define a custom android annotation (Eg. @Background)

Tags: android, annotations

Can any one suggest a proper order to define a custom annotation in JAVA(Android). So that if I annotate a method with @Background annotation, the method should work on background thread.

Comment: You need to use these annotations in Activity???

Comment: Yes. I need to use that annotation to make a method run in background. So that I can easily handle background tasks using this annotation.

Answer (score 4):

This might be of use for your need case [Creating custom Annotations](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-custom-annotations-example/). It seems like you would need to do `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)` and `@Target(ElementType.METHOD)` scope to achieve what you want. Then as you can see in the first example, you would go into the object and etc.

For a good example, look at what they do in [Dagger](https://github.com/square/dagger/blob/master/core/src/main/java/dagger/Module.java)

As a final note, this is old and you've probably designed what you wanted, but it probably isn't a good idea to do what you asked. There is cost to annotation usage and Runnable was built basically for what you seem to be trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Android's `Annotation` subtypes provide a wide variety of tools for what you are trying to do. In particular, take a look at the [thread annotations](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations.html#thread-annotations); I suspect that the `@WorkerThread` annotation does just what you want. The code inspection tools in Android Studio recognize these annotations and will automatically flag any code that it recognizes as violating the threading requirements (e.g., calling a UI thread method from a method annotated as `@WorkerThread`).

The code inspection tools also allow you to define your own annotations, but these are somewhat limited in what they can do. This is discussed in the section [Creating Enumerated Annotations](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations.html#enum-annotations).

Answer (score -4):

You can't use a custom annotation in JAVA(Android), because the android compiler doesn't support it. But maybe the follwing site can be helpful for you: http://androidannotations.org/

Comment: Aren't these custom annotations :)